# React - Cannot read properties of null ("reading useState") error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

I'm trying to do some form validation in react, and I'm getting this error "Cannot read properties of null (reading "useState").

I've done a bit of research on SO, and others have resolved this by including an onChange which setups the useState, but this hasn't resolved it. Any idea why this is happening? Would it be because it's attempting to load the form, and the values are initially empty?

```
import React from 'react'
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form'
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { Container } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { useState } from 'react';


const [form, setForm] = useState({});
const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});  // state is called in handleSubmit function

const setField = (field, value) => {
  setForm({
    ...form,
    [field]: value
  })
  // Check and see if errors exist, and remove them from the error object:
  if (!!errors[field]) setErrors({
    ...errors,
    [field]: value
  })
}

const findFormErrors = () => {
  const { email, password } = form;
  const newErrors = {}
  // email errors
  if (!email || email === "") newErrors.email = "cannot be blank";
  else if (email.length > 40) newErrors.email = "too long";

  if (!password || password === "") newErrors.password = "can't be an empty password";
  else if (password.length < 5) newErrors.password = "password is not long enough";

  return newErrors  // essentially returning the new errors, empty object

}

const handleSubmit = e => {
  e.preventDefault()

  const newErrors = findFormErrors();

  if (Object.keys(newErrors).length > 0) {
    setErrors(newErrors)
  } else {
    alert("thanks for signing up!");
  }
}

const theForm = () => {
  return (
    <Container>
      <Form className="reduceForm">
        <Form.Label className="contact">Contact Me</Form.Label>
        <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicEmail">
          <Form.Label>Email address</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control type="email" placeholder="Enter email"
            onChange={e => setField('email', e.target.value)}
            isInvalid={!!errors.name} />
          <Form.Control.Feedback type='invalid'>
            {errors.name}
          </Form.Control.Feedback>
        </Form.Group>
        
        <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicPassword">
          <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control type="password" placeholder="Password"
            onChange={e => setField('password', e.target.value)}
            isInvalid={!!errors.name} />
          <Form.Control.Feedback type='invalid'>
            {errors.name}
          </Form.Control.Feedback>
        </Form.Group>
        <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
          Submit
        </Button>
      </Form>
    </Container>
  )
}

export default theForm
```

Comment: Hooks needs to be inside of the component, not outside of it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```html
 const [form, setForm] = useState({});
    const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});
```

these needs to be inside the function.

Comment: Thanks Jagadeesh, this resolved my issue!

Comment: Specifically inside of functional components or react hooks.