# React Nextjs is broken cant useState or forms

Tags: reactjs, typescript, postgresql, prisma

im new to react so maybe i missed something. I am trying to create simple form for registration but seems like I cannot change the state.

`

```
import {useState} from 'react'


export const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({})

export  const handleChange = (event: any) => {
    const name = event.target.name
    const value = event.target.value
    setInputs(values => ({...values, [name]: value}))
  }

export  const handleSubmit = (event: any) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    console.log(inputs)
  }

type Props = {
  label: string
  placeholder?: string
  onChange: () => void
  name?: string
  value?:  any
}

export const TextField = ({ label, onChange, placeholder, name, value }: Props) => {
  return (
    <div style={{width:'100%'}}>
      <div className='text-sm my-2'>{label}</div>
      <input
        className='border-blue-200 border-2 rounded focus:ring-blue-200 focus:border-blue-200 focus:outline-none px-2'
        style={{ height: '45px', maxWidth: '280px', width: '100%', backgroundColor: '#0D0D0D' }}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        onChange={onChange}
        name={name}
        value={value}
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```

`

and in register file i have

`

```
<form action="" method="post">
          <div className='flex flex-col flex-wrap gap-y-5'>
            
              <TextField  name="email" value={inputs.email || ""} label='Enter Your email address:' onChange={() => {handleChange}} />
              <TextField name="password" value={inputs.password || ""} label='Enter Your Password:' onChange={() => {handleChange}} />
           
          </div>

          <div className='mt-7 flex items-center gap-x-2'>
            <PrimaryButton text='Register' onClick={() => {handleSubmit}} /> 
            <div className='text-sm'>
              Already Registered? <a onClick={() => push('/login')}>Login</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          </form>
```

`

i am getting this error

[image: state broke]

I was just trying to get the user input from email/pass and post to postgresql db but it say cannot read state

using @sachila-ranawaka answer produces this error

[image: why]

Comment: https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/rendering/server-and-client-components#convention

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/72403895/7785337 . The `useState` declaration needs to be inside the function component.

Comment: @ManirajMurugan even when I declare properly doesnt work. i am just trying to get user input. thats it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move the content inside the `TextField` component and exclude the `export` s

```
type Props = {
  label: string
  placeholder?: string
  onChange: () => void
  name?: string
  value?:  any
}

export const TextField = ({ label, onChange, placeholder, name, value }: Props) => {

   const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({})

   const handleChange = (event: any) => {
     const name = event.target.name
     const value = event.target.value
     setInputs(values => ({...values, [name]: value}))
   }

   const handleSubmit = (event: any) => {
     event.preventDefault()
     console.log(inputs)
   }

   return (
    <div style={{width:'100%'}}>

      ..........
```

Comment: ok doing like that shows different error cannot find "input/handleSubmit/onSubmit"